# What is the right/better approach to send images from nestjs to flutter

Tags: node.js, flutter, base64, multipartform-data, nestjs

I'm building simple flutter application with nestjs as back-end. I want to send details of users with their pictures (avatars). I'm able to send `Base64` encoded image from nestjs and `decode` it in flutter and vice-versa. But I'm not sure whether this is better approach, because if I fetch all user details from API, the response object will be too huge (too many `base64` encoded images). I'm looking for suggestion on:

*What is right / better approach to send single image file from Flutter to Backend (NestJS)?*

*What is  right / better approach to send multiple image file from Backend (NestJS) to Flutter?*

Answer (score 0):

The best approach in my opinion is just send the image with the data in a multipart/form-data request (image in binary blob) from flutter to nestjs, in nestjs you can handle in with fileUpload interceptor https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/file-upload

You can save the image in your server or anywhere and then save a  object like this

```
{
  name: 'Lorem ipsum',
  lastname: 'Lorem ipsum',
  profileUrl: 'server/profile1.jpg' // this can be array if you want save multiple images
}
```